# Como mostrar o registro que foi mais repetido na tabela MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Por exemplo, se eu fiz um registro do João umas 5 vezes ( ou seja, fiz 5 registros do João) e depois fiz o registro de outros nomes normalmente,sem repetir nem nada, eu queria saber como que dar um select mostrando o nome do João, já que ele foi o que mais se repetiu, alguem sabe como?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente o seguinte, Onde NomeColunaDuplicada seria a coluna que tem o João 5x e NomeTabela seria sua tabela

```
SELECT NomeColunaDuplicada, Count(*) as QtdRepeticoes FROM NomeTabela
GROUP BY NomeColunaDuplicada
HAVING Count(*) > 1
order by QtdRepeticoes desc;
```

Esse select vai trazer o registro repetido e quantas vezes ele foi repetido em ordem decrescente igual abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo o que foi mais repetido estará em primeiro, Mas caso queira retornar somente ele use:

```
SELECT NomeColunaDuplicada, Count(*) as QtdRepeticoes FROM NomeTabela
GROUP BY NomeColunaDuplicada
HAVING Count(*) > 1
order by QtdRepeticoes desc
limit 1;
```